# Eigenvalue decomposition

Tags: covariance-matrix, eigenvalues

Why is the eigenvalue decomposition of the covariance matrix formula, $UΛU^T$ (assuming T means transpose) and not $UΛU^{-1}$? Where $U$ is eigenvectors and $Λ$ is a diagonal matrix consisting of eigenvalues?

Comment: Hint: would $U\Lambda U^{-1}$ be symmetric in general?

Comment: Because it is symmetric. Look under “Matrix inverse via eigendecomposition” at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix